# How to do I update CUDA driver nvidia on Windows 10?

Tags: graphics, cuda, driver, updates, nvidia

I don't really know what is that, but I am installing a Python A.I that uses this. I am trying to update my **CUDA** for 3 hours. I already tried to download the **CUDA toolkit**, but it was no use. I installed that but happened nothing. I need to update my **CUDA driver**. Now the current version is **9.1.84**, I need **10.2**. Please, someone, help me.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Uninstall](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-microsoft-windows/index.html#uninstall-cuda-software) your current installation of CUDA. Note that the installation guide for CUDA is [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-microsoft-windows/index.html). Read the description in the [installation guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-microsoft-windows/index.html), go to this [page](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads), choose your OS, architecture, CUDA version ("11" will give you the latest version), and installer type (choose 'local' and then download a 2 to 3 GB installer file). Follow prompt and if any errors or warnings read them carefully and deal with them with a little help from Google!

Comment: Just noting that "11" (and "10") on the page you linked (https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads) refer to Windows version, not the CUDA version.